# How to get rid of this horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll, width

For the life of me I cant seem to get rid of the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of [this site](http://enviropost.com.au). I have tried everything (in my ability) and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on it for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a very basic answer you can just set `overflow-x: hidden` for the `body` tag. Although I'd recommend trying to determine why the widths of your elements are always bigger than the window...

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a crack. I have tried most of the day trying to figure out whats breaking it, I just can' t find the problem.

Comment: Edit: That works but I will leave it off tho see if anyone can find the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row.vc_custom_1488973579542` (the one with the big title) is not a direct child of a `.container`, but of a `<section>`.

Your theme uses a grid layout system based off of Bootstrap's columns, which uses left/right paddings on `.container`s and equal corresponding left/right negative margins on `.row`s. In full-width mode, not placing top level `.row`s inside a `.container` results in rows being `25px` larger than the `<body>`, creating a horizontal scrollbar.

Possible fixes:

- place this `.row` inside a `.container` (recommended)
- override default row margins for it:

```css
.row.vc_custom_1488973579542 { 
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0; 
}
```

- hide the overflow (not recommended):

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both worked but went with the recommended. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Simply ignore all over spacing**:

```
<style>

body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

</style>
```

**Or** you could go through all of your CSS and make sure that you don't accidentally have any "bleeding" borders or margins/padding.

Bleeding occurs when you set the width of an element to 20% and there is 5 of those elements, but then you add 10px margin causing part of it run off.

JSFiddle Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/9dcdurnj/4/

Do you notice that the fourth element is on the second line?  It's because margin happens outside of the styled object.

**Note**: there is a lot of other way to cause bleeding too. Like, with borders and etc. that aren't properly adjusted for.

I would, personally go with the overflow-x:hidden, but that's because I'm lazy.  But, by using the lazy way, overflow-x:hidden, you could impact some future uses of your code.  That being said, I think you should just us overflow-x:hidden.